# How to get key and values of an array using for loop()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

My array is below,

```
  "custominfo": [
    {
      "fb": "www.fb.com"
    },
    {
      "google": "www.google.com"
    }
  ],
```

I want fb i.e key and www.fb.com i.e value using for loop.I tried this,

```
for(var i = 0;i< custominfo.length;i++){
     console.log(i[0])
}
```

This prints,

```
{"fb":"www.fb.com"}
```

But how can i get key and value seperately. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < custominfo.length; i++){
   console.log(custominfo[i])
}
```

To get the keys, you can loop for `custominfo[i]`:

```
for (var k in custominfo[i]) {
   console.log('key:' + k);
   console.log('val:' + custominfo[i][k]);
}
```

Comment: How to get key?

Comment: I added code to get the key from the sample object you provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
var custominfo = [
    {
      "fb": "www.fb.com"
    },
    {
      "google": "www.google.com"
    }
  ]

for(var i = 0;i < custominfo.length;i++){
     console.log("Key: "+Object.keys(custominfo[i]));

     console.log("Value: "+ Object.values(custominfo[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below solution. Use 1 for `loop` for `custominfo` array and another one for keys of each object, it's will be fine if each object contains more than 1 key.

```js
var custominfo = [
  {
    "fb": "www.fb.com"
  },
  {
    "google": "www.google.com"
  }
];

for (var i=0; i<custominfo.length; i++){
   var elem = custominfo[i];
   var keys = Object.keys(elem);
   for (var j=0; j<keys.length; j++){
      console.log(keys[j]);
      console.log(elem[keys[j]]);
   }
}
```